# MySQL How can I select the Current User ID in a MySQL statement

Tags: mysql

How can I select the Current User ID in a MySQL statement?
Select Current_User will give the name and host but I need the ID.

Second question: Since the Host is returned as part of the Current_User, will a different current user be returned for the same User ID when the user is logged in from a different location then during the first login?

Comment: MySQL doesn't have ID numbers for users. The name and host are the unique identifiers for a MySQL user.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Like the comment from Barmar above, I don't know what you mean when you say user ID. MySQL users are identified as `user@host`.

You asked if the user would be different if they log in from a different location. The answer is *maybe!*

The `user@host` returned by `CURRENT_USER` depends on which user was matched when the client authenticated.

For example, suppose you have created users like:

```
CREATE USER 'arthur'@'localhost';

CREATE USER 'arthur'@'192.168.%';

CREATE USER 'arthur'@'%';
```

These are all technically different users. They can have different passwords, and be granted different privileges.

If your client connects from localhost using the UNIX socket, it authenticates as `arthur@localhost`.

If your client connects using a TCP/IP network connection from any host in the 192.168 subnet, it authenticates as `arthur@192.168.%`.

If your client connects using TCP/IP from any host outside that subnet, it authenticates as `arthur@%`.

---

Re your comment:

It's often the case that an application (like Wordpress) manages multiple "users" that are really just rows in a table in MySQL. But the app has to connect to the database before it can read those rows and validate the app users. So the app uses the credentials of one MySQL user to access the database. Then it authenticates the request with respect to one of the rows in its user table.

Therefore there are MySQL user(s), which are a different set than the Wordpress users.

Wordpress users are identified by an integer, as shown in the Wordpress manual for [`get_current_user_id()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_current_user_id/).

MySQL users are not identified by an integer. They are like `user@host` as I described above. These MySQL users are the ones which you would use to define a view or a procedure. They are not the same as Wordpress users; MySQL users have no integer ID.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. It helps. This is my scenario. I use the Wordpress Plugin  WPdatatables. I use it to store user specific selections. Based on the selections I provide user specific data. WPdatatables hasa %current_user_ID% placeholder which works in the plugin, but not in a MySQL view.  Now I am looking for a way to get the current user ID of the loged in user.
User specific data is stored with one colomn containing the userID. I could change this to current user, but when the user logs in from a different location I suspect he will not see the data  due to the @localhost addition.